# Strange Update Panel Issue with Devexpress Controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have some strange issue with Update Panel.

I am using Devexpress Controls, JQUERY AJAX in one of my applications. I have used Server side coding + Client side coding aproach i.e. using Jquery, JS and AJAX + Update Panel on some pages where aspxgridview is there.

I am creating a scenario via example situation according to the problem I have faced:

1) There are some ASPxcomboBoxes for e.g.County, State and City.

2) On client Selected index change of Country, I have fetched the data via AJAX and bind the states in State ASPxComboBox using JSON and same for the city combo on client index change of State.

3) On the city combo's index change, I have bound a ASPxGridView with some related data and ASPxGridView and City combo is wrapped in Update Panel as we cannot bind the ASPxGridView via AJAX so to avoid postbacks I have used update panel and its working fine.

4) If user doesn't selects any record from the Grid on submit click then its prompts the user that select any one record and I have kept the validation on server side button's click event.

Now, The problem is after submiting and validation occurs. The State's combos items are repeating for e.g. initial items were : --select--, USA and after validation occurs on submit its showing --select--, USA, --select--, USA.

**I have not bind the control on page load event as its binded via client side. The property of EnableSynchronisation is True to synchronise client and server items of aspxComboBox.**

When I saw using debugger when I click on submit. I have quick watched State combo on page load event and its items count is 4 as 2 are repeatative items.

**The problem is on even first line of page Load event when I Add Watch to it I get the items count as 4 that means items are posted wrongly to the server.**

**When I remove Update panel, everything works fine.**

I don't know why wrong items/ repeatative items are posted on server. Please help.

Comment: You clear the combobox items in each page load before it binds the items.

Comment: @Universal, I have not bound the ASPxComboBox on Page Load Event. I have BOUND it VIA AJAX using Client index change event of another combo. I HAVE NOT USED SERVER SIDE EVENTS.

Comment: As per the logic, whether it is client side or server side, first you try to clear the items each time before loading the items to the combo box.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Sorry I have forgot to mention that I have cleared the items in the bind function which I have defined client side using JQuery.

Comment: Any Views ? Kindly help. I am stuck. :(

Comment: Can you post your full code, so that it will be easier for the people to find the root cause of exact issue.

Comment: Sorry bro.. Due to Copyrights issue I cannot post the code as its a live project. I have not coded much for update panel as just placed controls inside it. Due to partial post backs, items don't get repeated. It only gets repeated when a button click event occurrs, I have examined the code of button click and found no issues.By the way, The main thing is the control i.e. **State which is not inside update panel repeating its values** after submit click even after I have not touched the control on button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the Issue.

Wrapped the Update Panel to State Combo.

Actually It was not needed as State Combo need not be refreshed via Server Operations as I have used AJAX to bind it on client.

But Wrapping the Update Panel to it did solved the issue.